# Have CentOS OpenJDK packages passed TCK compliance testing?

Tags: java, redhat-openjdk

Red Hat provides OpenJDK binary distributions that have passed TCK compliance testing, as documented in their [OpenJDK Life Cycle and Support Policy](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013).

The equivalent CentOS OpenJDK rpm packages carry the same version string, and appear to behave in exactly the same manner as their RHEL counterparts.  The contents, however, are slightly different. My assumption is that the CentOS builds use the same upstream source version as Red Hat, with differences coming from the system libraries or build environment.

This leaves me with some questions.

Are the CentOS OpenJDK builds put through TCK compliance testing?  If not, how reasonable is it to assume that the CentOS OpenJDK is of known quality? (I suppose there is the assurance that comes from using something as widely used as CentOS.)

For what it's worth - My customer understands that, if they really care about TCK, then perhaps they should be paying for Red Hat, or looking to an alternative like Azul. I'm trying to guide an informed decision.

Comment: Is this question material for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com), perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java TCK operates at a binary level. Only binaries can pass/fail the TCK. As far as the TCK is concerned you can build the same exact sources twice, using identical libraries, compiler flags and so on and each binary needs to be identified separately as having passed the TCK.

> Are the CentOS OpenJDK builds put through TCK compliance testing?

Red Hat - who I work for - publicly claim their binaries are TCK compliant. I dont know of anyone who tests or claims that for CentOS. By default, we should assume that they have not passed the TCK.

Comment: Thanks! This does makes sense, and matches up with what I'd expect. For what it's worth, I do think this builds a good argument for using a certified build (like Red Hat or Azul) if you're building a commercial product but don't wish to enter into an Oracle support contract.